# How to parse XML data and store it in string value in swift

Tags: ios, xml, string, swift

I have an API call which returns response as XML type, the thing is I have to get value from the xml data and store it in String, can you suggest how to get or map the value from the xml response?

Here my sample response from server :

```
responseString = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
<email-address>xxx02v@gmail.com</email-address>
</person>
```

Comment: try https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi which will make it much easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the native XML parsing you can `NSXMLParser` and `NSXMLParserDelegate`. it has many methods which is useful in parsing the XML data

Useful methods using NSXMLParserDelegate

```
    - parserDidStartDocument:
    - parserDidEndDocument:
    - parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
    - parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
    - parser:foundCharacters:
```

[Apple Doc: NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/)
[Apple Doc: NSXMLParserDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008632)

Example

```
var parser = NSXMLParser()
var posts = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()
var title1 = NSMutableString()
var date = NSMutableString()

func beginParsing()
    {
        posts = []
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"))!)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        element = elementName
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item")
        {
            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            title1 = NSMutableString()
            title1 = ""
            date = NSMutableString()
            date = ""
        }
    }

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!)
    {
        if element.isEqualToString("title") {
            title1.appendString(string)
        } else if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
            date.appendString(string)
        }
    }

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!)
    {
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item") {
            if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title")
            }
            if !date.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(date, forKey: "date")
            }

            posts.addObject(elements)
        }
    }
```

Full demo example:
[NSXML Parser Swift 1](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xml-parsing-using-nsxmlparse-swift)
[NSXML Parser Swift 2](https://medium.com/@lucascerro/understanding-nsxmlparser-in-swift-xcode-6-3-1-7c96ff6c65bc#.dsbm4jeat)